# Get raw URL from field link

Tags: entities

I have set up a node--home_page.tpl.php template with the following:

```
  <a href="<?php print render($content['field_primary_section_link']); ?>">
    <div id="primarySection">
       <?php print render($content['field_primary_section_image']); ?>
       <h1><?php print render($content['field_primary_section_title']); ?></h1>
        <?php print render($content['field_primary_section_body']); ?>

    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- END Primary Section -->
```

I want the anchor tag to contain the raw URL from the field_primary_section_link but it is pulling in everything around it. I just want the plain URL but am unsure how to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump `$content['field_primary_section_link']` using var_dump() or if you have [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed in your project you can use [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x) and you'll see a bunch of arrays there and check the raw url that you need.

Comment: Apologies. Think I explained wrong. I want the <a href="#"> to contain the URL from the field_primary_section_link.

Comment: you wanted the # to be set in the field_primary_section_link? sorry its a bit confusing to me :) may you can post some expected output?

Comment: I mean expected output

Comment: Thanks @ianroald. I have edited my question to maybe assist.

Comment: @roald is right, you have to debug that variable in order to get the desired field, it could be something like this `$content['field_primary_section_link']['und'][0]['url'];`

Comment: Thank you. The result I get is 
["field_primary_section_link"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        ["url"]=>
        string(8) "/tickets"
        ["html"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["query"]=>
        NULL
        ["fragment"]=>
        NULL
        ["absolute"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["display_url"]=>
        string(40) "https://mywebsite.com/tickets"
      }
    }
I tried <?php print render($content['field_primary_section_link'][0][display_url]); ?> and nothing it's not pulling. What error did I make?

Comment: have you try clearing your cache? might be a cached page

Comment: also make sure that the sequence of array is correct :)

Comment: I did do both but no luck. :(

Comment: can you post the full array?

Comment: the original array result

Comment: ["field_primary_section_link"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        ["url"]=>
        string(8) "/tickets"
        ["title"]=>
        string(26) "Purchase your tickets now!"
        ["attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(37) "Click to read more about this article"
        }
        ["html"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["query"]=>
        NULL
        ["fragment"]=>
        NULL
        ["absolute"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["display_url"]=>
        string(40) "http://www.mywebsite.com/tickets"
      }
    }

Comment: what module you're using on setting url? you using link module?

Comment: I'm uncertain what module, apologies. I didn't initally set the site up. I can tell you I am setting up a field in the content type using the Link field type, and I see in modules there is a Contextual Link module if that is related.

Comment: It must be a link module, can you try do dump this one? $content['field_primary_section_link']['#items'][0]['display_url'] I tried to create a same link you're using, I am using link module

Comment: Thank you!!!!! @iamroald I truly appreciate all of your time!

Comment: cool glad it work :)

Answer (score -1):

Use [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x). It gives you the absolute path if you feed it the file's FID.

Comment: op asked for link url, not file url